# regex mysql problem

Tags: php, mysql, regex

```
$res = $db->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM sam_users WHERE user_name RLIKE ?"); 
$res->execute(array($login.'[[:digit:]]*'));
```

I need a regex that returns all the accounts that match $login, or $login followed by one or more digits, but not followed by alpha values.

example
In my database I got account bla, bla2, bla3 and blabla

if I do a search on bla, i want to get back:
bla
bla2
bla3
BUT NOT blabla

My current code also returns blabla :/

Comment: Need to wrap your pattern with start/end anchors `^` `$` if you want to match start/end-of-string -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in this way

```
SELECT user_id FROM sam_users WHERE user_name regexp '^bla[0-9]*$'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the regular expression you should be using:

```
bla[0-9]*$
```

Comment: No, that still matches `blabla`: `select 'blabla' rlike 'bla[0-9]*$';` => 1